# Re-render a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In react, I could easily re-render a view by passing results from controller. I wish not to use React at this stage and was wondering if it's possible with JQuery?

I have few objects on page, and when clicked, I should see its content. Click the other object, I see its content etc. Sense? I was inspired by [this dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/3047167-Timesheet).

I may not be doing this the right way but this is what I have:

**Controller:**

```
def index
  selected_contract = params[:selected_contract] || current_user.contracts.last.id
  @contracts = current_user.contracts.order(created_at: :desc).all
  @selected_contract = current_user.contracts.find_by(id: selected_contract)
end
```

**View:**

```
<% @contracts.each do |contract| %>
  <button class="ui button test" id="<%=contract.id%>"><%=contract.name%></button>
<% end %>

......................................
When clicked, show its content
....................................

<%= @selected_contract.name %>
```

**JS:**

```
$( ".ui.button.test" ).click(function(e) {
  let { id } = this
  console.log(id)
  $.ajax({
    url: `/url/${id}`,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      //$('#listview').redraw()
      console.log('success')
    }
  });
});
```

Routes are set properly so I get the params in the controller just fine. Is there a re-render a view, just like rerender a prop in React for jquery? Am I doing this the correct way?

Comment: take a look here https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy. You basically need a `.js.erb` or an equivalent, and also your action needs to respond to `js`, in the template(.js.erb file) you can use jquery to replace/render whatever you need in the page..

Comment: I see. I'll have a read. Thanks.

Comment: @fanta YEAAHHHH that works! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery listview this should work.

```
$( "#listview" ).listview( "refresh" );
```

Reference 
https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

or since its rails you can reload or render the partial view in your server side as well.